# Google App Engine for Java meet DFP API- V201302

Tags: google-app-engine

I am not able to access DFP Api using latest version (v201302) on Google App Engine, it works fine at localhost:8888 but gives error at Google App Engine.

Error: Exception retrieving data; nested exception is: 
    java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: Attempt to access a blocked recipient without permission. (mapped-IPv4)

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed by adding right jars from maven repository.
see complete [servlet here](http://knowledge-serve.blogspot.in/2013/06/dfp-with-google-app-engine.html).